# How is Shelob's name known?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-two-towers

In Tolkien's world, there are quite a few "magical" beasts that have proper names: dragons for example, like Smaug. One can assume that their names are known either because their creator was still around at that time (and thus could tell their name) or because the creature can speak (like Smaug).

What about Shelob however? She is said to be the last daughter of Ungoliant, and was in her lair even before Sauron got to Mordor, so her origins are long forgotten. She also doesn't seem to be very talkative. And from her behavior as presented by orcs, it doesn't seem like she would engage in conversations even with them, assuming she could talk.

Yet, we can quote Shagrat in the chapter *"The choices of master Samwise"*:

> "But Shelob was on the go."
>
> "Nothing gets by Shelob when she's on the hunt."

**How can Shagrat possibly know Shelob's name?**

Comment: I'll answer properly later (if nobody else does first). Shelob made a deal with Gollum (see Shelob's Lair in The Two Towers), so she definitely can communicate in some way. Also remember that the spiders in Mirkwood can talk (Flies & Spiders in The Hobbit).

Comment: @isanae There's no reason not to accept the first answer that answers your question adequately. Askers can *always* switch their acceptance to another answer later, as long as the question is not locked or deleted.

Comment: I'm confused. A name is what people call you. Some names are what people call themselves.

Comment: @galdre OP is basically asking whether "Shelob" is the former or the latter and, if it's the latter, how they found out.

Comment: @hyde There's not really a need to get another answer to a question once it has an answer that solves it. If you really want to provide an answer to an already-answered question, the existence of an answer shouldn't dissuade you. You can also avoid the issue of missing questions by picking a different view, such as newest.

Comment: @TylerH I mostly disagree. If there is already an accepted answer that is low quality, I am less likely to spend time on writing a higher quality one. I wish I was more altruistic than that, but I gotta have more internet points. Pretty sure I'm not unique in that regard.

Comment: @isanae I accepted the answer because it provides a referenced canon answer to the question. There is nothing more to add to it so I don't see why I should have to wait.

Comment: @Fatalize The two other answers quite clearly show that there _was_ more to add to it. Understand that I am not questioning which answer you accepted, this is your prerogative, just that waiting a bit longer might get you additional answers with more details. Because you asked a question, I assume you are interested in having more information about on that subject.

Comment: @isanae The difference is that acceptance can only be given once, and is 15 points, and can *only* be given by the OP. An upvote is still 10 votes, there's no limit, and can be given by *anyone*. If you want internet points, add an answer. You're losing out on all those upvotes by saying "because I can't get those 15 unique points, it's not worth getting potentially 100 or 200 or even more (usually a comically large amount on SciFi.SE) points than that by writing an answer. That's like saying "because I can't get the first cookie, I don't want any of the other 50". ;-)

Comment: @isanae The two other answers, while interesting, are more interpretation than the first one, which is a precise and official answer to the question. There is nothing "more to it" since it perfectly answers the question.

Comment: Census taker. You can imagine the conversation: CT: "Good afternoon, sir or madam, I'm here as a representative of the Royal Census. Can you tell me your name, please?" S: "Shelob". CT: "Age?" S: "Ancient". CT: "Can you be a *bit* more specific..?" S: "No". CT: "Fine. Now, how many individuals live at the residence, including all family members, extended family members, and boarders, but not renters who have a separate address/domicile?" S: "Many". CT: "Once again, sir or madam, I must ask you to be more specific". S: "Lots". CT: "Is this a bad time..?" S: "Only for YOU..!!!!" CT: "Yipe..!"

Answer (score 189, accepted):

From Letter 144:

> Shelob (English representing C.S 'she-lob' = female spider) is a translation of Elvish *Ungol* 'spider'.

'Shelob' is therefore *not*, strictly speaking, a name, but rather a description.  People aren't calling her by name, they're calling her "the Spider".

Comment: Can't believe I never caught that before.  Bilbo calling the spiders "lazy lob" and the female spider being called "she-lob"

Comment: Woah. In the Spanish translation, Shelob is one of the few characters that gets its name translated to actual Spanish. Aragorn is Aragorn, Gollum is Gollum, Ungoliant is Ungoliant... but Shelob is called "_Ella Laraña_", with "_Ella_" meaning "She" and "_Laraña_" being a contraction of "_La Araña_", i.e. "The (female) Spider". It always bothered me because I didn't see a reason to change a character's name like that... It makes **SO MUCH** more sense now!

Comment: @walen and, in Portuguese, *Laracna*. Indeed, makes sense now. =)

Comment: @walen - Tolkien wrote a guide for translators, and in it he recommends that Shelob be translated.

Answer (score 129):

### "Shelob" probably wasn't her name

Fun fact, Sam's name is actually *Banazîr* and his father Ham is *Ranugad*. Tolkien's stories are meant to be translations of old books into English. He did, however, take certain liberties as to how to translate names.

"Shelob" is a simple [compound word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_word) containing *she*, for "female", and *lob*, an archaic word for "spider", deriving from Old English [*loppe*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loppe#Old_English):

> sense of "spider, silkworm" from Proto-Germanic **lubbō*, **lubbǭ* ‎(“that which hangs or dangles”), from Proto-Indo-European **lep-* ‎(“to peel, skin”).

(yuck, so *lob* and *leper* seem to have a common origin)

Going from "female spider", we can translate this back into the original Quenya<sup>1</sup> (of which there are many forms, but let's take the good old *Parmaquesta*, the high-elvish form) and you'd get something like *Ungoliel*. It's rather close to *Ungoliantë*, but *liantë* means "shadowy, dark"<sup>2</sup>, whereas the *-iel* suffix means *female* (Tinúviel, etc.)

From there, knowing the original Quenyan, we can come up with the proper English name of *She-Spider* or the more baroque *Fem-Spider*.

My assumption therefore is that the original work, passed down through the ages, did not name the spider, but used the name *Ungoliel* instead. Tolkien did not want to use the uncouth *She-Spider* and decided to be creative and use *Shelob*.

As for her *real* name, it seems to have, unfortunately, been lost. She might never have had one.

<sup><sup>1</sup>The Lord of the Rings is derived from the *Red Book*, texts compiled by, among others, Bilbo and Frodo. Strictly speaking, it was written in Westron, the "common speech", but there isn't much information about that language, so I chose Quenya instead.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>The etymology of *Ungol* and *liantë* are unclear and have been switched a few times. *Ungol* was initially "dark", but that obviously wasn't the case in the Lord of the Rings. That would be an awesome new question though.</sup>

Comment: This makes me wish I could vote up or down at most twice, so I could vote this up more than the accepted answer. As it is i shall just vote for this one.

Comment: @PJTraill I think you should vote each answer on its own merit. The accepted answer is clear, concise and informative.

Answer (score 53):

### “Shelob” may be a name of the orcs’ invention

Shelob is what the orcs call her, not necessarily her real or original name.

> ‘You won’t go again, you say? Curse you, Snaga, you little maggot! If
>   you think I’m so damaged that it’s safe to flout me, you’re mistaken.
>   Come here, and I’ll squeeze your eyes out, like I did to Radbug just
>   now. And when some new lads come, I’ll deal with you: I’ll send you to
>   Shelob.’
>
> <sub>*Return of the King*</sub>

Indeed, we *know* she has names in other languages:

> Presently they were under the shadow, and there in the midst of it
>   they saw the opening of a cave. ‘This is the way in,’ said Gollum
>   softly. ‘This is the entrance to the tunnel.’ **He did not speak its
>   name: Torech Ungol, Shelob’s Lair.**
>
> <sub>*The Two Towers*</sub>

Neither of the words in the phrase meaning “Shelob’s Lair” seems to contain the word Shelob, or any derivative thereof. Indeed, one word is “Ungol, ” as in Ungoliant, which is probably the part that means “Shelob.” “Ungol” may even just mean “spider,” but then so might “Shelob.”

It’s also true that the narrator calls her “Shelob.” This should not surprise us, though: the narrator also uses the name “Gandalf,” which is neither what the elves called Gandalf in his earliest days as an Istari, nor his original name as a Maia.

The point is this: **Shelob would not need to be capable of communication in order to have a name.**

### Even if it’s not, Shelob might be able to communicate

The spiders of Mirkwood could communicate in Bilbo’s tale (*The Hobbit*). Even if we account for dramatic license, Shelob’s progenitor, Ungoliant, was certainly capable of speech (as illustrated in the *Silmarillion*). Let us not forget that neither Ungoliant nor Shelob was any mere beast: Ungoliant was a spirit of great power, and Shelob was closely descended from her. It’s not suprising that she might be capable of speech, or might have been capable of speech in bygone times when her hunger was not so great.

Comment: Great answer, but I will accept the other one as it is a definitive proof with reference that Shelob is indeed just "The Spider".

Comment: You seem to me to be making the assumption that "Torech Ungol, Shelob's Lair" is a name and then a translation with your line "Neither of the words in the phrase *meaning* "Shelob's Lair" [...]" (emphasis mine). To me it reads "Torech Ungol (the name of the place), Shelob's Lair (the description of the place)". Parenthetical citations mine.

Comment: There are many faulty etymological assumptions in this answer, making most of the first part useless. 1) "Shelob" isn't a "root", it's an English compound. 2) _Shelob_ means "female spider", _Ungol_ means "spider", _Torech Ungol_ means "[secret] hole of the spider". 3) "Shelob's Lair" is a rough translation of "Torech Ungol" from English to Sindarin. 4) "Shelob" is not in Black Speech, there's like 20 words that exist and they mostly come from the Ring.

Comment: @isanae - Mmmm, I am not sure what exactly you are taking issue with. "Shelob" does appear to be the counterpart of "Ungol," meaning-wise. Whether it is what the orcs are calling her in English or some fictional language is not really relevant. The part about the Black Speech is indeed in error, though.

Comment: 1) You say _Shelob_ means "spider", but it means "female spider". 2) I can't make any sense out of "Neither of the words in the phrase meaning “Shelob’s Lair” seems to have the root Shelob."  3) Then you mention Black Speech, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @isanae - I said it *might* mean "spider." And it seems it does, plus a gender marker. The gist is that it seemed clear to me that "Torech Ungol" meant something like "Shelob's Lair," thus indicating that she was being called something different in a different language.

Comment: You seem to be saying that because the lair is called _Torech Ungol_, not _Torech Shelob_, "Shelob" cannot be her given name. But then you mention Gandalf, are you saying it's not a given name either? Like I said, it's probably just me, but I can't make any sense out of the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 6):

### Shelob is an orkish moniker for her, not her actual name

In his guide for translators, (published in *A Tolkien Compass* and *The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion*), Tolkien says that "Shelob" was meant to sounds like a suitable spider name in an Orkish tongue, and this was done by deriving the name from dialectal english for spider, to give it a foreign feel.

Tolkien therefore includes it on his list of names he'd recommend translating, and gives the etymology.

> **Shelob.** Though it sounds (I think) **a suitable name for the Spider, in some foreign (Orkish) tongue,** it is actually composed of *She* and *lob* (a dialectal E. word for ‘spider’). (Cf. *The Hobbit*, Chapter 8.) The Dutch version retains *Shelob*, but the Swed. has the rather feeble *Honmonstret*.
> <sub>Nomenclature of The Lord of the Rings</sub>

The reference made to *The Hobbit* is to the song Bilbo sings to antagonize the spiders:

> Lazy **Lob** and crazy Cob
> are weaving webs to wind me.
> I am far more sweet than other meat,
> but still they cannot find me!
> <sub>*The Hobbit* - Chapter 8 - "Flies and Spiders"</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As described on Shelob's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelob):

> As Tolkien admitted in a letter to his son, Shelob "is of course only
>   'she + lob'," - lob being an archaic English word for spider,
>   influenced by Old English loppe or "spider". The word is not related
>   to "cob" nor "cobweb". Old English attercoppe (meaning "spider") is
>   derived from atter meaning "poison" and coppe meaning "head"; Tolkien
>   used "attercop" as well as "cob" and "lob" in The Hobbit, where Bilbo
>   Baggins sings songs taunting the giant spiders in Mirkwood: "Attercop,
>   Attercop, Old Tomnoddy" and "Lazy Lob and Crazy Cob".

She is also referred to as "Her Ladyship", but I cannot find the reference at the moment.